# Redirect does not save address to user's history - alternative besides Route?

Tags: redirect, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

```
{window.location.href.includes("search") && !query  && (
            <>
                <Redirect
                    to={{
                        pathname: "/search/?q=" + window.location.href.split("q=")[1],
                        state: {
                            queryString: window.location.href.split("q=")[1],
                            query: window.location.href.split("q=")[1],
                            type: type,
                        },
                    }} 
                ></Redirect>
            </>
        )}
        
        {query ? (
            <Redirect
                to={{
                    pathname: "/search/?q=" + queryString,
                    state: {
                        queryString: queryString,
                        query: query,
                        type: type,
                    },
                }}
            ></Redirect>

        ): null}
```

What could I use in place in Redirect here? I need the current address (before the redirect) to be stored to the user's history, so they can still get to it using the "back" button. Or is there some extra parameter I could add to the Redirect? I tried using "from" and giving the current pathname, but that still resulted in odd behaviour (skipping a page and going to the one 2 pages back, or going "back" to the current page). Using react-router-dom but open to using something else to get what I need. The portion above is from Header.js, and below is the relevant portion from App.js (no routing/redirecting happens in SearchResult.js)

```
<Route path="/search/:id" exact component={SearchResult}/>
```

I have also tried using Route as other answers have suggested (see code below), but get an error message (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')

```
{window.location.href.includes("search") && !query  && (
            <Router>
                <Route
                    to={{
                        pathname: "/search/?q=" + window.location.href.split("q=")[1],
                        state: {
                            queryString: window.location.href.split("q=")[1],
                            query: window.location.href.split("q=")[1],
                            type: type,
                        },
                    }} 
                ></Route>
            </Router>
        )}
        
        {query ? (
            <Router>
            <Route
                to={{
                    pathname: "/search/?q=" + queryString,
                    state: {
                        queryString: queryString,
                        query: query,
                        type: type,
                    },
                }}
            ></Route>
            </Router>

        ): null}
```